# jQuery.live() and cucumber tests

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, testing, selenium, cucumber

Does selenium support jQuery.live() when used as a default Capybara javascript driver in cucumber tests? If no what alternatives would you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that Selenium really cares what jQuery methods you use. I use Selenium with Cucumber/Capybara and have used .live() before, and everything was fine.

As a slightly unrelated side note, if you're using jQuery 7.x or up, you should use the .on() method instead of .live(), as .live() is deprecated for some subtle bugs and performance issues.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

http://api.jquery.com/on/

**EDIT** As per request, I use cucumber-rails 1.2.1, which pulls in capybara. Currently my capybara is at 1.1.2, and it pulls in selenium-webdriver, which I have at 2.21.2.

Comment: You're right I had a local problem with my js files compilation. Thanks for helping!